# Android SharedPreferences Issue - Get Data From Another Class

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I'm trying to pass data without using Intents so that certain classes can access the data.  So  what I decided to do is use SharedPreferences.  When I run the code I have a Toast in the End() method display the url I set in the Start() method.  The toast displays my default message but not the url I have stored in the SharedPreferences.

Here is the code for the Start() method:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Start extends Activity { 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String uriStr = "http://www.google.com";
    URI uri = null;

    try {
        uri = new URI(uriStr);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String trackUri = uri.toString();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit(); 
    prefEditor.putString("track_uri", trackUri);
    prefEditor.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), End.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Here is the code for the End() method:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class End extends Activity { 
private Context mContext;

public End() { 
}

public End (Context context) { 
    mContext = context;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    String trackUri = "Test";
    //SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    sharedPref.getString("track_uri", trackUri);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), trackUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Basically all I want to do is get data from another class without having to keep track of it and pass it using Intents when I can another class.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Start` replace

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

**EDIT:**

Just realized! You're not setting your trackUri variable.

```
sharedPref.getString("track_uri", trackUri);
```

should be

```
trackUri = sharedPref.getString("track_uri", trackUri);
```

---

Note: If you're simply trying to pass the String, you could add it to the Intent extras in Start. E.g.

```
intent.putExtra("track_uri", trackUri);
```

Then retrieve in End:

```
String uriString = getIntent().getStringExtra("track_uri");
```

Comment: Good spot.  I hadn't even noticed that.

Comment: I tried that.  It still gives me the "test" string not the url